# Activate updated service worker on refresh

Tags: service-worker

When a service worker updates, it doesn't take control of the page right way; it goes into a "waiting" state, waiting to be activated.

Surprisingly, the updated service worker doesn't even take control of the tab after refreshing the page. Google explains:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/service-worker/lifecycle

> Even if you only have one tab open to the demo, refreshing the page
>   isn't enough to let the new version take over. This is due to how
>   browser navigations work. When you navigate, the current page doesn't
>   go away until the response headers have been received, and even then
>   the current page may stay if the response has a `Content-Disposition`
>   header. Because of this overlap, the current service worker is always
>   controlling a client during a refresh.
>
> To get the update, close or navigate away from all tabs using the
>   current service worker. Then, when you navigate to the demo again, you
>   should see the horse [updated content].
>
> This pattern is similar to how Chrome updates. Updates to Chrome
>   download in the background, but don't apply until Chrome restarts. In
>   the mean time, you can continue to use the current version without
>   disruption. However, this is a pain during development, but DevTools
>   has ways to make it easier, which I'll cover later in this article.

This behavior makes sense in the case of multiple tabs. My app is a bundle that needs to be updated atomically; we can't mix and match part of the old bundle and part of the new bundle. (In a native app, atomicity is automatic and guaranteed.)

But in the case of a single tab, which I'll call the "last open tab" of the app, this behavior is not what I want. I want refreshing the last open tab to update my service worker.

(It's hard to imagine that anybody actually *wants* the old service worker to continue running when the last open tab is refreshed. Google's "navigation overlap" argument sounds to me like a good excuse for an unfortunate bug.)

My app is normally only used in a single tab. In production, I want my users to be able to use the latest code just by refreshing the page, but that won't work: the old service worker will remain in control across refreshes.

I don't want to have to tell users, "to receive updates, be sure to close or navigate away from my app." I want to tell them, "just refresh."

How can I activate my updated service worker when the user refreshes the page?

EDIT: There's one answer I'm aware of that's quick, easy, and wrong: `skipWaiting` in the service worker's install event. `skipWaiting` will make the new service worker take effect as soon as the update downloads, while the old page tab is open. That makes the update unsafely nonatomic; it's like replacing a native app bundle while the app's running. That's not OK for me. I need to wait until the user refreshes the page of the last open tab.

Comment: There's one answer I'm aware of that's quick, easy, and unsafe: `skipWaiting` in the service worker's `install` event. I don't want to just randomly replace my service worker as soon as the update has been discovered, in the middle of users' work. I need to wait until the user refreshes the page.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I wrote a blog post explaining how to handle this. https://redfin.engineering/how-to-fix-the-refresh-button-when-using-service-workers-a8e27af6df68

I also have a working sample on github. https://github.com/dfabulich/service-worker-refresh-sample

There are four approaches:

1. **`skipWaiting()` on installation.** This is dangerous, because your tab can get a mix of old and new content.
2. **`skipWaiting()` on installation, and refresh all open tabs on `controllerchange`** Better, but your users may be surprised when the tab randomly refreshes.
3. **Refresh all open tabs on `controllerchange`; on installation, prompt the user to `skipWaiting()` with an in-app "refresh" button.** Even better, but the user has to use the in-app "refresh" button; the browser's refresh button still won't work. This is documented in detail in [Google's Udacity course on Service Workers](https://www.udacity.com/course/offline-web-applications--ud899) and the [Workbox Advanced Guide](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes#offer_a_page_reload_for_users), as well as the `master` branch of my [sample on Github](https://github.com/dfabulich/service-worker-refresh-sample).
4. **Refresh the last tab if possible.** During fetches in `navigate` mode, count open tabs ("clients"). If there's just one open tab, then `skipWaiting()` immediately and refresh the only tab by returning a blank response with a `Refresh: 0` header. You can see a working example of this in the `refresh-last-tab` branch of my [sample on Github](https://github.com/dfabulich/service-worker-refresh-sample/tree/refresh-last-tab).

Putting it all together...

In the Service Worker:

```js
addEventListener('message', messageEvent => {
    if (messageEvent.data === 'skipWaiting') return skipWaiting();
});

addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    event.respondWith((async () => {
        if (event.request.mode === "navigate" &&
        event.request.method === "GET" &&
        registration.waiting &&
        (await clients.matchAll()).length < 2
        ) {
            registration.waiting.postMessage('skipWaiting');
            return new Response("", {headers: {"Refresh": "0"}});
        }
        return await caches.match(event.request) ||
        fetch(event.request);
    })());
});
```

In the page:

```js
function listenForWaitingServiceWorker(reg, callback) {
    function awaitStateChange() {
        reg.installing.addEventListener('statechange', function () {
            if (this.state === 'installed') callback(reg);
        });
    }
    if (!reg) return;
    if (reg.waiting) return callback(reg);
    if (reg.installing) awaitStateChange();
    reg.addEventListener('updatefound', awaitStateChange);
}

// reload once when the new Service Worker starts activating
var refreshing;
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange',
    function () {
        if (refreshing) return;
        refreshing = true;
        window.location.reload();
    }
);
function promptUserToRefresh(reg) {
    // this is just an example
    // don't use window.confirm in real life; it's terrible
    if (window.confirm("New version available! OK to refresh?")) {
        reg.waiting.postMessage('skipWaiting');
    }
}
listenForWaitingServiceWorker(reg, promptUserToRefresh);
```

Comment: I just don't get your second and 3rd solution.  you're saying to refresh all open tabs. even if someone checks your sample, your comments are wrong. If I have 5 tabs, and i refreshed one of them which figured out there's new service worker, that tab will show button telling me if i want to refresh. That button won't be shown on other tabs and if clicked yes, only this tab will be refreshed. not the other ones. Why are you saying all open tabs refresh?

Comment: The third solution is given a thorough demonstration in [Google's Udacity course on Service Workers](https://www.udacity.com/course/offline-web-applications--ud899). Give it a try. What you'll find is: if the client side is configured to reload on controllerchange, and you click the in-app refresh button in any tab, the controllerchange event fires on all tabs, so they all refresh immediately.

Comment: @DanFabulich using approach 3, i see the banner even for users visiting the very first time, who don't have any service worker for my site.

Comment: Dan, what is reg for you, the registered service worker?

Comment: @DanFabulich this solution really helps and specially your blog link is very impressive and explained very well. Thanks :)

Comment: @DanFabulich thank you for your fantastic article, it's really helpful. Have there since been any updates to service workers that make this any easier?

Answer (score 73):

There are conceptually two kinds of updates, and it isn't clear from your question which we're talking about, so I'll cover both.

## Updating content

Eg:

- The text of a blog post
- The schedule for an event
- A social media timeline

These will likely be stored in the cache API or IndexedDB. These stores live independently of the service worker - updating the service worker shouldn't delete them, and updating them shouldn't require an update to the service worker

Updating the service worker is the native equivalent of shipping a new binary, you shouldn't need to do that to (for example) update an article.

When you update these caches is entirely up to you, and they aren't updated without you updating them. I cover a number of patterns in the [offline cookbook](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/offline-cookbook/), but [this is my favourite one](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/offline-cookbook/#cache-then-network):

1. Serve page shell, css & js from a cache using the service worker.
2. Populate page with content from the cache.
3. Attempt to fetch content from the network.
4. If the content is fresher than what you have in the cache, update the cache and the page.

In terms of "update the page", you need to do that in a way that isn't disruptive to the user. For chronological lists this is pretty easy, as you just add the new stuff to the bottom/top. If it's updating an article it's a bit trickier, as you don't want to switch text from underneath the user's eyes. In that case it's often easier to show some kind of notification like "Update available - **show update**" which, when clicked, refreshes the content.

[Trained to thrill](https://jakearchibald.github.io/trained-to-thrill/) (perhaps the first ever service worker example) demonstrates how to update a timeline of data.

## Updating the "app"

This is the case where you *do* want to update the service worker. This pattern is used when you're:

- Updating your page shell
- Updating JS and/or CSS

If you want the user to get this update in a non-atomic, but fairly safe way, there are patterns for this too.

1. Detect updated service worker "waiting"
2. Show notification to user "Update available - **update now**"
3. When the user clicks this notification, postmessage to the service worker, asking it to call `skipWaiting`.
4. Detect the new service worker becoming "active"
5. `window.location.reload()`

Implementing this pattern is part of my [service worker Udacity course](https://www.udacity.com/course/offline-web-applications--ud899), and [here's the diff of the code before/after](https://github.com/jakearchibald/wittr/compare/task-update-notify...update-interaction).

You can take this further too. For example, you could employ some kind of semver-esque system, so you know the version of the service worker the user currently has. If the update is minor you may decide calling `skipWaiting()` is totally safe.

Comment: I am indeed developing an "app." Is there really no way to `skipWaiting` on refresh? Implementing my own in app refresh button seems like a hack.

Comment: The two options above don't depend on the type of thing you're building, but the thing you're updating. You'll likely use both patterns in the same app or site. What kind of content are you looking to update?

Comment: I'm developing a game. I want to update the game's code, including JS.

Comment: I'm trying to implement the method for updating the app as described above and in the Udacity course, but I never seem to get the 'controllerchange' event. However, using console logs I was able to see the skipWaiting message post, and I can view the service workers in Chrome's dev tools and see the old one disappear as the new one takes over. Any idea why that would be? Edit: [GH commit](https://github.com/davmillar/DavesMapper/commit/a1cc1431f724fecbfacf631b1b9d12498f976351).

Comment: Why do you need to update the ServiceWorker when you change js or css? I know the google workbox guides do it that way, but why can't the service worker just fetch the updated files and replace them in the cache. Then sw would only need update when the sw is really updated.

Comment: You can code it that way if you want, it's just more for you to write.

Comment: Will I encounter too much mess if I try to follow these service worker brilliant recipes if I am using PWA Starter Kit? Actually I don't know even where do I start: where is my (beloved) service worker, if I am using PWA Starter Kit? I thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: @FINDarkside I have a similar use case to the OP (though not actually a game). Fetching updated files while running is exactly what I **don't** want; it's started running with version X and must continue to run version X regardless if X+1 is now available when I fetch some later file; it's not guaranteed that app state set up by version X will be compatible with files from X+1. So everything is served from cache without the SW even checking for new versions. Only the SW itself is fetched to check for new versions; tying the update of everything else to the SW lifecycle prevents mixups.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to Dan's answer;

**1. Add the `skipWaiting` event listener in the service worker script.**

In my case, a CRA based application I use [cra-append-sw](https://github.com/bbhlondon/cra-append-sw) to add this snippet to the service worker.

> **Note:** if you are using a recent version of `react-scripts`, the snippet below is [automatically added](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/2394) and you won't need to use `cra-append-sw`.

```
self.addEventListener('message', event => {
  if (!event.data) {
    return;
  }

  if (event.data === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});
```

**2. Update register-service-worker.js**

For me, it felt natural to reload the page when the user navigates within the site. In the register-service-worker script I've added the following code:

```
if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
  // At this point, the old content will have been purged and
  // the fresh content will have been added to the cache.
  // It's the perfect time to display a "New content is
  // available; please refresh." message in your web app.
  console.log('New content is available; please refresh.');

  const pushState = window.history.pushState;

  window.history.pushState = function () {
    // make sure that the user lands on the "next" page
    pushState.apply(window.history, arguments);

    // makes the new service worker active
    installingWorker.postMessage('SKIP_WAITING');
  };
} else {
```

Essentially we hook into the native `pushState` function so we know that the user is navigating to a new page. Although, if you also use filters in your URL for a products page, for example, you may want to prevent reloading the page and wait for a better opportunity.

Next, I'm also using Dan's snippet to reload all tabs when the service worker controller changes. This also will reload the active tab.

```
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
  });

navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange', () => {
  if (refreshing) {
    return;
  }

  refreshing = true;
  window.location.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though the OP has disagreed with skipWaiting, skipWaiting is actually the correct solution for many apps, especially single page apps.

Open your precache in DevTools, check if there are any lazy loaded files. If there aren't - meaning everything in your precache are fetched immediately on page load, then it's safe to call skipWaiting, which will delete the old precache, replace with new assets (including the new index.html), waiting to be served on the next refresh. Since all the old assets are already in memory, which are running with the old index.html, there's nothing wo worry about.

(If you see a file in the precache but you aren't sure whether it's downloaded on page load, reload and watch the network traffic in DevTools yourself)

If you do have lazy loaded assets, then it indeed could cause a problem, but that's not a new problem created by service worker. Imagine your user opened a tab, then you deploy a new version, then the user clicks something which triggers a lazy load, but that asset is no longer on your server. This is an old problem. Precache unintentionally solved this problem, but you shouldn't rely on it, instead you should have your own exception handling logic, unless your app was designed to leverage the precache from the very beginning.

Comment: Lazy loaded assets are not a problem when they have unique names (e.g. including hashes like Webpack does) and are *never* overwritten and *never* deleted.

Answer (score 0):

What I do:

In serviceworker:

```
self.addEventListener("activate", event => {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.delete(cacheName)
    );
});
```

In index.html:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange', function() {
    window.location.reload(true);
});
```