# Force reload skipping Service Worker in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Service Workers can interfere with the refresh button (by design). On desktop Chrome, you can hold shift and click the refresh button to do a hard reload, ignoring any installed ServiceWorker.

Is there a way to force a reload ignoring the SW in JavaScript?

(I want this so I can give mobile users a button to push if the SW starts misbehaving. Phones don't have a shift key.)

Comment: I'll tell you one thing I tried that doesn't do what I want.
 [`window.location.reload(true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) (the `forcedRefresh` parameter), is generally supposed to be equivalent to shift-refresh, but in my tests, `location.reload(true)` doesn't override/ignore the SW; as far as SWs are concerned, it's the same as `location.reload(false)`. (Is that a bug in Chrome??)

Comment: If you want to delete all caches you could use `caches.delete` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers#Deleting_old_caches You could communicate with the service working from your js code (button click handler) and the service worker message handler could delete the caches (or only some). When the service worker is done then reload the page: http://craig-russell.co.uk/2016/01/29/service-worker-messaging.html#.We2hlHWCzHQ

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you `unregister` the Service Worker before refreshing, the next page load will load without the Service Worker.

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(function(reg) {
  if (reg) {
    reg.unregister().then(function() { window.location.reload(true); });
  } else {
     window.location.reload(true);
  }
});
```

Comment: Where should I use this code? Inside the window's "beforeunload" event handler? What are the implications of unregistering the SW on each reload?

Comment: @Arik I never intended this code to be run on each reload. I intended to offer users an on-screen "force reload" button; the code would appear in the button's click handler. I don't think it makes sense to force refresh on every reload; at that point, I think you really just want to uninstall the service worker completely, without replacement. (Alternately, if you just want to activate an updated service worker on refresh, that's a [different question entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40100922/54829).)

Comment: Dan, I was on a quest to resolve another issue (can't get my SW to respond to fetch events after a hard reload), and I mistakenly related your answer with my issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what I commented on:

page script:

```
if('serviceWorker' in navigator){
  // Register service worker
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js')
  .then(
    reg =>
      console.log("SW registration succeeded. Scope is "+reg.scope)
    ,err =>
      console.error("SW registration failed with error "+err)
  );
}

const send_message_to_sw = (msg) =>
  new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
      // Create a Message Channel
      const msg_chan = new MessageChannel();

      // Handler for recieving message reply from service worker
      msg_chan.port1.onmessage = (event) => {
          if(event.data.error){
              reject(event.data.error);
          }else{
              resolve(event.data);
          }
      };

      // Send message to service worker along with port for reply
      navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage(
        msg
        , [msg_chan.port2]
      );
  }
);

document.body.addEventListener(
  "click"
  ,()=>
    send_message_to_sw(
      {
        action:"delete"
        ,cache:/^v1$/
        ,url:/.*bundle.js$/
      }
    )
    .then(
      (msg)=>
        console.log("deleted:",msg)
    )
);
```

Service worker:

```
console.log("SW Startup!");

// Install Service Worker
self.addEventListener(
  'install'
  ,(event)=>
    console.log('installed!')
);

// Service Worker Active
self.addEventListener(
  'activate'
  ,(event)=>
  console.log('activated!')
);
self.addEventListener(
  'fetch'
  ,(event) =>
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request)
      .then((resp) =>
          resp 
          || 
          fetch(event.request)
          .then(
            (response) =>
              caches.open('v1')
              .then(
                (cache) => {
                  cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
                  return response;
                }
              )  
          )
      )
    )
);
self.addEventListener(
  'message'
  ,(event) =>{
    const data = event.data || {};
    if(data.action === "delete"){
      var p = 
        caches.keys()
        .then(
          (keyList) =>
            keyList
            .filter(
              key=>data.cache.test(key)
            )
        )
      ;
      if(data.url === undefined) {
        p = p.then(
          (keyList) =>
            Promise.all(
              keyList
              .map((key) =>{
                caches.delete(key);
                return key;
              }
            )
          )
        )
      }else {
        p = p.then(
          (keyList) =>
            Promise.all(
              keyList
              .map((key) =>
                caches.open(key)
                .then(
                  (cache)=>
                    Promise.all([
                      cache
                      ,cache.keys()
                    ])
                )
                .then(
                  ([cache,items])=>
                    Promise.all(
                      items
                      .filter(item=>data.url.test(item.url))
                      .map(
                        item=>{
                          cache.delete(item);
                          return key + ":" + item.url
                        }
                      )
                    )
                )
            )
          )
        )        
      }
      return p.then(
        (keys)=>
          event.ports[0].postMessage(
            keys
            .reduce(
              (acc,item)=>acc.concat(item)
              ,[]
            )
          )
      );
    }
  }
);
```