# Handle cache when pushing in production a new web app that doesn't use a service worker from an old web app that was using one

Tags: reactjs, browser-cache, service-worker, next.js

I am trying to update a react.js app that was created with facebook's `create-react-app` *and that uses a registered service worker* to a `Next.js` app to enjoy Server-Side Rendering *but doesn't use a service worker.*

When pushing in production, my previous users are stuck with the cached version of the old app.

**Question: How can I make this update successful?** All the relevant resources I could find were about updating an app that keeps a service worker..

Thank you!

Comment: You might need to inline the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46881906/force-reload-skipping-service-worker-in-javascript) in index.html (which hopefully CRA proxy might not have cached).

Comment: The approach outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33986976/how-can-i-remove-a-buggy-service-worker-or-implement-a-kill-switch should work.